# Handle Multiple Custom Filters in Spring Security Filter Chain

Tags: spring-security

I need to secure my REST api with token(JWT) based approach.
 My application has two authentication systems
 1. Azure AD (users from Azure) 
 2. Custom JWT Authentication (users from db)
I need to allow(authorize) users from both the systems(Azure & DB) to access api. So, I have to check a token against both the auth systems and validate if anyone of them returns true.

Authorization Implementation :
1. I used AADAuthenticationFilter(extends OncePerRequestFilter) in spring security chain to validate Azure token

(source taken from : https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot using azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter (0.2.0))

2. I implemented Custom JWTAuthenticationFilter(extends OncePerRequestFilter) in Spring security chain to validate Custom JWT Token.

I used both of them in my SecurityConfiguration class .

But Security fails if any one of the filter(AADAuthenticationFilter or JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter) from Spring security chain fails to validate.
My requirement is to allow the request if either of the token is true.

Please suggest me with the best approach!.

I tried to do below approach but not successful : 
1. I tried to handle my Custom JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter on exception, Do I have any approach to pass the request to second filter?
2. If token is Success in first token filter validation then how do i skip the second filter (or remove the second filter from the stack)?

How to bypass the request to meet my requirement ?

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    @EnableOAuth2Sso
    public static class ApiWebAzureSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AADAuthenticationFilter aadAuthFilter;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();

            // Added AADAuthenticationFilter for Azure 
            http.addFilterBefore(aadAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebJWTSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter jwtTokenAuthenticationFilter;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

            // Add our custom JWT security filter 
            http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint()).and()
                .addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }

}

----------------------------
Please find my filter implementation

@Component
public class JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Autowired
private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Extract token from header
        String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken((HttpServletRequest) request);
        //validate the token 
        if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token,request, response)){
            Authentication auth = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);

            if (auth != null) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

}
```

I have to allow the request if the token is validated against atleast 
 one of the authentication systems .

Comment: I have exactly this case running in production, plus including custom procedures in Azure AD filter validation. I think the answer should be in the implementations of the filters themselves or the underlying `AuthenticationProviders` if any

Comment: 1. I agree with "the ans should be in impl of filters", Can you  explain a procedure on how to handle ?                                                                                                           
2. I don't think AuthenticationProviders that are used to fetch user information will help, In my scenario  two different token are already been provided . Please correct me

Comment: You should provide your filters implementation so that it could be tested, just as suggested in How do I ask a good question? > How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry for the delay . I have added my filter implementation to above code and you can see microsoft azure filter implementation at https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/blob/master/azure-spring-boot/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/spring/autoconfigure/aad/AADAuthenticationFilter.java

Comment: If in case its not clear I can add my sample project to git and share .